# Is it haram to look after your family, by doing haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, family

In our world it takes a great deal to look after a family especially if you have nothing to start with. When you have a wife and kids, it is really hard to look after them and satisfy their basic needs. Instead of begging or doing crimes, does doing a proper job, even if it is haram in some sense, affect your after life? I've heard the story of a prostitute who has been forgiven by Allah just because she fed a thirsty dog ([Hadith](http://www.sacred-texts.com/isl/bukhari/bh4/bh4_541.htm)).

- Is it haram to look after one owns family by doing haram because there is no other option? For example, a bar tender.
- How will it affect the family members? How their afterlife would be?

Comment: Accepting a haram job should be the very last option.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to pay heed that haram is haram, and you cannot justify yourself to do haram (forbidden) as you said:

> In our world it takes a great deal to look after a family especially
>   if you have nothing to start with. When you have a wife and kids it
>   really hard to look after them and satisfy their basic needs. Instead
>   of begging or doing crimes, does doing a proper job even if it is
>   haram in some sense, affect your after life?

Your issue can be like the following matter to some extent (I can remembered that  I heard a story ...) that:

> (approximate story): Someone was stealing (I reckon pomegranate), then
>   was helping them to poor individuals (as charity), so the Prophet
>   (peace be upon him and his family) considered his practice as a haram
>   ...

Otherwise, if your words were right, then Allah would allow poor people to steal or do haram activities for their families (for their expenses)...

---

Eventually, there could be two final solutions for you:

- Endeavor to deal with the current condition.
- Endeavor to find a halal job (even with a lower income).

By observing the items above Allah (God willingly) would keep blessing (Barekah) in your money... anyhow, hopefully you do not do haram (although it seems you won't do that, since it was significant as you searched about that).

یارزاق

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Can you also say if a bar tender job is haram?

Comment: Unfortunately I ought to remark: Yeah, since it is related to a haram act, as being mediator of wine, beer, and such haram drinks and so on (I reckon it is deemed as a haram act from both Sunni and Shia). If you'd like to be in heaven ... then you should bear some difficulties, shouldn't you? Thus try to find another job (even lower job...) for a halal income (for the sake of Allah), then Allah will help you... ان شاءالله